# How to resolve dependency hell in NPM with peerDependencies

Tags: jquery, npm, dependencies, package-control, peer-dependencies

## Setup:

Given the following points

- *my_library* makes extensive runtime use of **jquery**.
- in *my_library* the **jquery** required via **npm** is `^3.3.1` by default (because of security fixes in it). However it is compatible also with **jquery >=2.2.0** (but is not specified in `package.json`, yet)
- the *my_library* is used in a *custom_project* via **npm**.
- the *custom_project* requires also *outer_library*, that is using different & conflicting **jquery** versions (e.g. let's say **jquery 1.7.3**).
- the *custom_project_2* instead just requires *my_library* in `dependencies`.

## Problems:

- installing *custom_project* will provoke duplicate dependencies, messing up **jquery** for one of the two libraries.
- the **jquery** version in *my_library* `dependencies` specifies a suggested version (in order to avoid critical vulnerabilities) but doesn't say anything about which **jquery** minimum version is compatible with *my_library*

## Eventual solution:

To avoid **jquery** dependency duplication (1.7.3 for *outer_library* and 3.3.1 for *my_library*) I could move my **jquery ^3.3.1** from `dependencies` to `devDependencies`, so I'll get the **3.3.1** on development while it won't be installed on production (`npm install --only=prod`) and just **jquery 1.7.3** will be installed.

But this:

- doesn't guarantees that *my_library* will get a compatible **jquery** version, so *my_library* could easily break.
- - adding `jquery@>=2.2.0` inside *my_library* `peerDependencies` will at least raise a *WARN* asking to resolve the conflict manually installing a specific version in *custom_project* (even though probably it can't be solved).
- feels wrong to me since **jquery** is a runtime `dependency` and shouldn't go into `devDependencies` (with unit-testing tools, etc.). In fact **jquery** won't be installed in the *custom_project_2*, when installing on *production* (so *my_library* will break)

## Questions

1. How can I manage to satisfy both use cases of dependency by *my_library*?
2. (A) In case the *outer_library* would require a **jquery** compatible with my `peerDependencies` definition (`>=2.0.0`), would I STILL need to install **jquery** manually? Or **npm** will resolve a common version?
3. (B) Are there cases where `peerDependencies` doesn't complain and doesn't require to install anything manually? (as long as semvers are honoured?)
4. (A) Does it make sense to put a dependency like **jquery** (high probability of conflicts) **either** inside `peerDependencies` (with an as loose as possible *semver*) **and** inside `dependencies` with the recommended version?
5. (B) Would that work correctly in every setup **and** with *NPM* version `<3` (peerDependencies automatically installed) and `>=3` (manual installation needed)?

Appreciated if you can answer even to a part of the questions

Answer (score 0):

Is it safe to assume the dependency of my_library on jquery is a peer dependency? And that you are on the development team of my_library?

If so, the best solution might be to change my_library's peer dependency on jquery into a regular dependency. If I understand [this article](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2016/08/24/understanding-the-npm-dependency-model/) correctly, only peer dependencies can generate conflicts between packages, regular packages get installed into subdirectories so my_library get's it's own version of jquery installed, seperate from outer_library.

It might just be impossible to convert a peer dependency into a regular dependency however. https://medium.com/@jacob.h.page/common-npm-mistakes-51bf8989079f

> Is your module a plugin for some library or framework? Then that library/framework is a peer dependency. The consuming application is responsible for selecting and integrating a set of mutually-compatible plugins; the plugins themselves should not introduce said framework directly, but should instead specify a maximally-inclusive version range to make the job of integration as easy as possible.

Your other option would be to wait for outer_library to release a new version that IS compatible with the latest jquery.